# Pegar valor de um input e jogar valor em outro input pelo Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, select, input, while

Boa noite, precisaria que o usuário escolha quantas classes quer no select e então o sistema calcule o valor e coloque no outro input, não sei onde estou errando se puderem me ajudar

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    // classe 1 classe
        var valorDaMarca = parseFloat('1855.80');
        // demais classes
        var valorDasDemaisClasses = parseFloat('805.20');
      
      var classe = document.getElementById("classes").value
      
        function valorTotal(){
            switch (classe) {
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("pfn_vlr_total").value = valorDaMarca;
            break;
        case 2:
        document.getElementById("pfn_vlr_total").value = valorDaMarca + valorDasDemaisClasses;
        break;
        }
     }
    
</script>
    
<html>
    
    <select id="classes" name="classes" onchange="valorTotal();">
      <option value="1">1 Classe </option>
      <option value="2">2 Classes</option>
      <option value="3">3 Classes</option>
      <option value="4">4 Classes</option>
      <option value="5">5 Classes</option>
      <option value="6">6 Classes</option>
    </select>
    
    <input id="pfn_vlr_total" name="pfn_vlr_total" readonly ="readonly" type="text" class="total text-center" value="0,00" required>
```

vou deixar foto de algo parecido porém com botões rádio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço atenção e ajuda de todos

Comment: vc precisa ler o valor da classe dentro da função "valorTotal". quando leu o valor ainda não tinha sido escolhido, e está usando um valor desatualizado, já o que o evento é `onchange`, ou seja, se mudou precisa ler novamente

Comment: Entendi o seu ponto mas não sei como faço para ler novamente tem alguma ideia? Para mim como é onchange toda vez que eu mudasse a opção deveria atualizar o valor

Comment: claro que não, vc leu o valor o `value` num determinado momento, não vai atualizar automaticamente, e vc quisesse manter o valor original? como fazer? só mover a linha para dentro da function para ler o valor no momento que mudar

Answer (score 1):

Prozyn, a questão é que você está usando um switch indevido aí. E também creio que o código que você escreveu não está correspondendo ao que eu entendi que seria seu caso de uso.

### O Switch

Switch é uma forma estruturada de retornar valores baseado no conteúdo de uma variável, com um "default" para tratar de casos não endereçados anteriormente. Para melhor explicar:

```
function barulhoDoAnimal(animal){
    switch(animal){
        case "cachorro":
            return "latido";
        case "gato":
            return "miado";
        default:
            return "desconhecido";
    }
}

barulhoDoAnimal("gato") // retorna "miado";
barulhoDoAnimal("cachorro") // retorna "latido";
barulhoDoAnimal("cavalo"); // retorna "desconhecido";
```

### O que está dando errado

Seu caso sempre vai retornar `1855.80` por conta dos seguintes fatores:

- Na computação de uma forma geral, o valor 1 representa "verdadeiro", enquanto o valor 0 representa "falso".
- Quando uma variável possui algum tipo de valor no JS, ela é verdadeira. Quando ela tem valor nulo, ela é falsa.

Então quando você coloca a variável "classe" no switch, ela está preenchida com um valor padrão. Não sendo nula, ela é verdadeira. Sendo verdadeira, ela cai no caso de uso 1 (verdadeiro), e retorna a variável `valorDaMarca`.

### Como consertar

Ainda não me está 100% clara a lógica por trás do seu caso, mas pelo que eu entendi, o preço de 1 classe é fixo em 1855.80, e cada adicional seria 805.20. Correto?

Se for esse o caso, perceba que pra cada opção que você colocou, você associou um valor. Quando ocorre uma mudança, o JavaScript dispara um evento (no caso, você usou o evento "onChange"). O valor desse evento vai ser o valor da opção que você selecionou. Vamos fazer uso disso:

```
// Associando os valores a constantes
const valorPorClasse = 805.20;
const valorDaMarca = 1855.80;

function valorTotal(event){
    // Colocando o valor selecionado em uma variável e transformando em inteiro
    let quantidadeDeClasses = parseInt(event.target.value);

    // adicionando o valor da marca à multiplicação das demais quantidades
    let valorAPagar = valorDaMarca + ((quantidadeDeClasses - 1) * valorPorClasse);
    
    // associando ao input
    document.getElementById("pfn_vlr_total").value = valorAPagar
}
```

Comment: Sua logica está certa...peguei seu código e joguei no jsfiddle mas o problema continua...o input não sai de 0.00 vou deixar o link aqui do js fiddle caso queira olhar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h0wmbznx/#&togetherjs=6zuKRkb5o2